# How do I test for players in a specific area on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make an adventure game, and I'm making springs, but I can't seem to get the `/testfor` command to work. What do I do?

Comment: What's the whole command you tried?

Comment: /testfor @a[x=(xpos) y=(ypos) z=(zpos) r=1]

Comment: After that I use a fill command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `/execute`

```
/execute @a[x=6,y=3,z=10,dx=1,dy=0,dz=1] ~ ~ ~ effect @s levitation 1 1 true
```

Within the target selector `@a[]` you specify the starter coordinates with `x=`, `y=`, `z=`, and then the distance with `dx=`, `dy=`, `dz=`. the dx dy dz is the difference, so if `x=10` and `dx=5` you test for an area from 10 to 15, and this works the same for the other once as well both for positive numbers and negative.

Comment: There's a slight problem there. I use Edu edition. And I've tried the dx, dy, and dz. It just says syntax error. Plus, I'm using a fill command with sticky pistons and slime blocks. Not an effect command.

Comment: I'll try it out in the Edu version later. It sould work. Just let me know: Do you intend to fill in the pistons and slimes at the same time or with a delay?

Comment: I intend to fill the block under the sticky piston with a redstone block.

Comment: The command works fine for me, you can also replace the dz, dy ,dz with r=1. And replace effect etc. with `fill x y z x2 y2 z2 redstone_block`, but if you'r only setting one block you should use `setblock x y z redstone_block` instead.